# Three Variable Transformation and Independence

Tags: statistics, transformation, independence

If $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ are independent, identically distributed random variables and $Y_1$, $Y_2$, and $Y_3$ are functions of them, how do I show that the $Y$ variables are mutually independent? Can I show $f(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)=f(Y_1)f(Y_2)f(Y_3)$, or do I have to do it pairwise, ie. $f(Y_1,Y_2)=f(Y_1)f(Y_2)$ etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's one way to do it. You don't need to do it pairwise if you want to show all three are independent of one another. In fact pairwise independent does not imply independence.

So all in all, you want to show

$$f_{Y_1,Y_2,Y_3}(y_1,y_2,y_3) = f_{Y_1}(y_1)f_{Y_2}(y_2)f_{Y_3}(y_3)$$

Comment: Thanks! I just found the page in my book and it says the same. (My upvote will show when I get a higher reputation on this website.)

Comment: @Stephanie Sure, no problem. For your reference, when you find an answer acceptable or correct on this site when you ask a question, you signify this by clicking the check mark next to the answer. It will then turn green.